# Cron job for magmi import

Tags: php, magento, import, cron, magmi

Hi I'm trying to make a cron job for importing products into my magento.
I've got it all working just on an ad hoc basis but now I need a cron.

Ideally I would like to use the wget as that's the most straightforward.

So I'm using
wget "http://www.xxxxxx.com/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?profile=default&mode=xcreate&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine"  -O /dev/null

but I'm having problems with this error message
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Coming up - which trys for 20 times and then gives up.

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be?
Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Magmi CLI Interface](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line) to handle cron job running (as HTTP connections may have timeouts and such).

I would run the following command on your cron job:

```
php /path/to/magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php -mode=create
```

You can define a custom profile and mode by referencing the documentation here:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line

Comment: Thanks I just tried that but got this error PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  -1 in /var/www/vhosts/deal-buster.co.uk/httpdocs/magmi/inc/magmi_engine.php on line 211
startup:Performing Datasouce Lookup...
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRecordsCount() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/deal-buster.co.uk/httpdocs/magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 1309

Comment: I think this was me and the wrong url - seems to be ok now - thanks for listening to an old hand!

Answer (score 2):

Ive just created an extension for Magento that allows you to run Magmi via Magento's cron. This maybe able to help you

Download it free here -> https://github.com/cameraki/Magento-Magmi-Via-Cron-Extension/

Makes sense I post the code here in case the link goes offline, so here it is. ps, since I made a readme with the extension on github I have added this information at the bottom to help you get started.

app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Oli
 * Date: 02/11/2017
 * Time: 17:05
 */

/* Change importer to the name of your Magmi directory */
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir() . "/importer/plugins/inc/magmi_datasource.php");
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir() . "/importer/integration/inc/productimport_datapump.php");

class Oli_Magmi_Cron {

    const LOG_DIRECTORY = "oli-extensions.log";

    public function runMagmi()
    {


        try {
            $directory = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . '/import/';
            $magmiCsvFile = $directory . 'magmiUploadReady.csv';

            if(!file_exists($magmiCsvFile)) {
                throw new Exception('CSV file for Magmi to upload cant be found.');
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = date('F jS (l) Y h:i:s A') . " === MAGMI (" . __METHOD__ . ") === Could not load todays magmiupload file. It must not have run today. This script will now stop: ".$e->getMessage();
            Mage::log($message, null, self::LOG_DIRECTORY);
            die();
        }

        $productArray = $this->csvToArray($magmiCsvFile);

        $indexes = 'catalog_product_attribute,catalog_product_price,cataloginventory_stock';
        $mode = 'update';
        $profile = 'cronUpdatePrices';
        try {
            $this->import($productArray, $mode, $profile);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = date('F jS (l) Y h:i:s A') . " === MAGMI (" . __METHOD__ . ") === There was an issue importing the products: ".$e->getMessage();
            Mage::log($message, null, self::LOG_DIRECTORY);
        }
        try {
            $this->reindex($indexes);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = date('F jS (l) Y h:i:s A') . " === MAGMI (" . __METHOD__ . ") === There is a problem with the reindex function: ".$e->getMessage();
            Mage::log($message, null, self::LOG_DIRECTORY);
        }
        /* log that it actually ran */
        $message = date('F jS (l) Y h:i:s A') . " === MAGMI (" . __METHOD__ . ") === Has finished running";
        Mage::log($message, null, self::LOG_DIRECTORY);

    }



    public function csvToArray($filename)
    {
        $productArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filename));
        array_shift($productArray);
        $newProductArray = array();
        /* Customise the item array index's to match the file you are importing */
        foreach ($productArray as $key => $item) {
            $newProductArray[$key]['sku'] = $item[0];
            $newProductArray[$key]['buy_price'] = $item[1];
            $newProductArray[$key]['price'] = $item[2];
            $newProductArray[$key]['store'] = $item[3];
            $newProductArray[$key]['price_updated'] = $item[4];
            $newProductArray[$key]['amazon_euros'] = $item[5];
            $newProductArray[$key]['amazon_dollars'] = $item[6];
            $newProductArray[$key]['qty'] = $item[7];
            $newProductArray[$key]['is_in_stock'] = $item[8];

        }
        return $newProductArray;
    }



    private function import($items, $mode, $profile)
    {
        if (count($items) > 0) {
            try{

                $dp = new Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump();
                $dp->beginImportSession($profile, $mode);
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $dp->ingest($item);
                }
                $dp->endImportSession();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $message = date('F jS (l) Y h:i:s A') . " === MAGMI (" . __METHOD__ . ") === Seems to be an issue with the import function: ".$e->getMessage();
                Mage::log($message, null, self::LOG_DIRECTORY);
            }
        }
    }

    private function reindex($string)
    {
        /** @var $indexer Mage_Index_Model_Indexer */
        $indexer = Mage::getModel('index/indexer');

        $processes = array();

        if ($string == 'all') {
            $processes = $indexer->getProcessesCollection();
        } else {
            $codes = explode(',', $string);
            foreach ($codes as $code) {
                $process = $indexer->getProcessByCode(trim($code));
                if ($process) {
                    $processes[] = $process;
                }
            }
        }

        /** @var $process Mage_Index_Model_Process */
        foreach ($processes as $process) {
            $process->reindexEverything();
        }
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Oli_Magmi>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Oli_Magmi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <oli_magmi>
                <class>Oli_Magmi</class>
            </oli_magmi>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <update_prices_via_magmi>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>30 3 * * 2</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>oli_magmi/cron::runMagmi</model>
                </run>
            </update_prices_via_magmi>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Oli_Magmi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Oli_Magmi>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Oli_Magmi>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Magento Magmi Via Cron Extension**

Magento extension to run Magmi via Magento's cron from a CSV file

Note: This only works if you have Magmi (Magento Mass Importer)

**What does this do?**

Magmi allows you to make changes to products in bulk and fast. Its fast because its a direct import into the database. So use Magmi with caution and backup your database before you import.

This extension allows you to run Magmi automatically using Magento's cron. Great for updating product pricing automatically every day, or changing stock levels in bulk once a week.

**Can I use it out the box?**

You need to make sure you have Magmi on your server. Then:

- On line 10 & 11 of app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php change the
  "/importer/...." to the location of your Magmi install. Eg,
  "/magmi/...."
- On line 23 of app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php change $magmiCsvFil
  to be the address of the CVS file you are importing from. Once you
  have changed this, change the lines around line 66 to map the columns
  from the CSV file into an array. The keys of
  $newProductArray[$key]['...'] should match the attributes you are
  changing. Eg, if you want to update stock levels, you will use
  $newProductArray[$key]['qty'] since 'qty' is what Magento's stock
  levels are.

**Customisation**

- On line 36 of app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php this sets which
  Magento settings you want to re-index. The ones I add are:
  catalog_product_attribute catalog_product_price
  cataloginventory_stock You may want to add more or change these.
- On line 37 of app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php this is Magmi mode.
  "create" creates and updates items, "update" updates only, "xcreate"
  creates only.
- On line 38 of app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php change this to match
  the name of the profile you have created in Magmi. You can use
  'default' if you want to use the default profile however this is
  worth looking at because you want to make sure On the Fly indexing is
  turned off becauase this extension re-index's your magento store at
  the end. If you use a profile that has On the Fly indexing, it will
  re-index after each product, taking up a lot of server load for no
  reason.

**More info**
You can find more information about the Magmi DataDump API here -> http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Magmi_Datapump_API

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios I had to run Magmi from Magento cron job so I had something like this:

```
/**
 * Includes Magmi files
 */
protected function _includeMagmi()
{
    $magentoBaseDir = Mage::getBaseDir();
    require_once($magentoBaseDir . DS . 'magmi' . DS . 'inc' . DS . 'magmi_defs.php');
    require_once($magentoBaseDir . DS . 'magmi' . DS . 'integration' . DS . 'inc' . DS . 'magmi_datapump.php');
}

/**
 * Runs Magmi to update/create for specified data
 *
 * @param string $profile Magmi import profile (@see magmi/conf/
 * @param string $mode
 * @param array $data
 */
protected function _runMagmiImport($profile, $mode, array $data)
{
    $this->_includeMagmi();

    $logger = Mage::getModel('mario/magmi_logger');

    /** @var Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump $dataPump */
    $dataPump = Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance('productimport');
    $dataPump->beginImportSession($profile, $mode, $logger);
    foreach ($data as $update) {
        $dataPump->ingest($update);
    }
    $dataPump->endImportSession();

    return $logger;
}
```